# Error using Facebook Graph api to get email, name?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I have created application in Android integrated with Parse.com for Facebook and twitter integration.

I login with facebook using ParseFacebookUtils which gives me session access token which in turns i use it to call graph API.

Earlier it worked.

But now i get following error:

```
  Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {oauth=WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_token" "Error validating access token: Session does not match current stored session. This may be because the user changed the password since the time the session was created or Facebook has changed the session for security reasons."}

    04-22 21:35:17.631: W/msgr(:<default>):k(30067): com.facebook.http.protocol.e: [code] 190 [message]: Error validating access token: Session does not match current stored session. This may be because the user changed the password since the time the session was created or Facebook has changed the session for security reasons. [extra]:
```

This is graph API REST call i make:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/me?email,name&access_token=<access-token>
```

If i use same graph API from Graph API explorer it returns values but not from application which worked earlier.

[I changed password few days back but its login and storing user to parse but not getting response for graph API]

Comment: Looks like your access token has simply expired or been invalidated by your password change. (I assume when you are trying this request in Graph API Explorer, you are not using that same access token, but the access token GAE automatically provides?) So you need to go through the login flow again, to get a fresh token.

Comment: i tried clearing cache for my as well facebook app.. Tried with other account as well :(

Comment: cleared your app data? ParseUser stores itself in the app data. not the cache

Answer (score 0):

Try it with another facebook account, and if it works you must renew you token for the account where you changed password.

Have you tried to log in with another account in your app ?

Comment: And the error is still the same ? 
That <access-token> how is written in your code ?

Comment: access token is string.. it just replaces <access-token> token